# altair failing to vconcat facet charts

Tags: altair

I have two pairs of relatively simple faceted charts, but when I try to concat them, nothing shows up (in Colab):

```
ci_chart = alt.Chart(select_cis).mark_errorbar(ticks=True).encode(
  x=alt.X('date:T'),
  y=alt.Y('ci_lower:Q'),
  y2=alt.Y2('ci_upper:Q'),
  color='arch:N',
  strokeWidth=alt.value(2),
).facet('arch:N')
ci_chart
```

[image]

```
sample_size_chart = alt.Chart(select_cis).mark_bar().encode(
  x=alt.X('date:T'),
  y=alt.Y('sample_size:Q'),
  color='arch:N',
).properties(
    height=100
).facet(column='arch:N')
sample_size_chart
```

[image]

So when I try to concat them like the following, nothing shows up:

```
all_charts = alt.vconcat()
all_charts &= ci_chart
all_charts &= sample_size_chart
all_charts
```

The javascript console shows this error then:

```
pauseOutputUntil: promise rejected Error: Undefined data set name: "scale_concat_0_child_layer_0_main"
    at J (vega.min.js:82)
    at dx.na.getData (vega.min.js:1014)
    at vega.min.js:505
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eF (vega.min.js:505)
    at bF (vega.min.js:505)
    at Dw (vega.min.js:503)
    at vega.min.js:558
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Ui (vega.min.js:558)
```

Not sure why I'm getting `Undefined data set name`. Shouldn't vconcat just work with whatever charts there is?

*Note 1*: I don't hit this issue if I don't facet the individual rows.

*Note 2*: I tried first doing vconcat and then facet, but then I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'VConcatChart' object has no attribute 'facet'
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Here's the dataset:
|    |   ci_lower |      ci_upper | arch   | date                |   sample_size |
|---:|-----------:|--------------:|:-------|:--------------------|--------------:|
|  0 |  -14.0166  |  -4.39809     | ARM    | 2021-06-18 00:00:00 |           720 |
|  1 |  -11.3035  |   2.17015     | X64    | 2021-06-18 00:00:00 |           481 |
|  2 |  -19.2621  |  10.3276      | X64    | 2021-06-19 00:00:00 |           111 |
|  3 |  -44.3235  | -17.1238      | ARM    | 2021-06-20 00:00:00 |           123 |
|  4 |  -25.2304  |  21.9643      | X64    | 2021-06-20 00:00:00 |            37 |
|  5 |  -15.6512  |  -5.73696     | ARM    | 2021-06-21 00:00:00 |           810 |
|  6 |   -8.76779 |   0.516278    | X64    | 2021-06-21 00:00:00 |           759 |
|  7 |  -15.9351  |  -5.05429     | ARM    | 2021-06-22 00:00:00 |           527 |
|  8 |  -15.1192  |  -5.82563     | ARM    | 2021-06-23 00:00:00 |           739 |
|  9 |   -9.39934 |   0.00359764  | X64    | 2021-06-23 00:00:00 |           595 |
| 10 |  -15.0108  |  -5.6558      | ARM    | 2021-06-25 00:00:00 |           726 |
| 11 |  -22.8807  |   4.37449     | X64    | 2021-06-25 00:00:00 |           106 |
| 12 |  -14.7288  |  -3.73698     | ARM    | 2021-06-26 00:00:00 |           622 |
| 13 |  -10.2891  |   0.00145495  | X64    | 2021-06-26 00:00:00 |           703 |
| 14 |  -13.5252  |  -1.0572      | X64    | 2021-06-27 00:00:00 |           498 |
| 15 |  -17.7667  |  -7.12236     | ARM    | 2021-06-28 00:00:00 |           684 |
| 16 |  -16.3516  |   3.74576     | X64    | 2021-06-28 00:00:00 |           204 |
| 17 |  -15.6634  |   9.14817     | X64    | 2021-06-29 00:00:00 |           118 |
| 18 |  -38.607   |  -9.49601     | ARM    | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 |           123 |
| 19 |  -10.6489  |  -0.745364    | X64    | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 |           771 |
| 20 |  -10.6798  |  -2.19765     | X64    | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 |          1120 |
| 21 |  -13.7216  |  -2.49986     | ARM    | 2021-07-02 00:00:00 |           574 |
| 22 |  -12.1509  |   1.21277     | X64    | 2021-07-02 00:00:00 |           507 |
| 23 |  -13.6414  |  -4.13389     | ARM    | 2021-07-03 00:00:00 |           731 |
| 24 |  -20.6895  |   2.95152     | X64    | 2021-07-03 00:00:00 |           124 |
| 25 |  -12.1999  |  -0.000800218 | ARM    | 2021-07-05 00:00:00 |           447 |
| 26 |  -18.2576  |   7.47327     | X64    | 2021-07-05 00:00:00 |           116 |
| 27 |  -14.2627  |  -4.30436     | ARM    | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |           729 |
| 28 |  -32.0441  |   8.47457     | X64    | 2021-07-06 00:00:00 |            37 |
| 29 |  -11.379   |  -1.21069     | ARM    | 2021-07-07 00:00:00 |           677 |
| 30 |  -17.0245  |   2.82563     | X64    | 2021-07-07 00:00:00 |           123 |
| 31 |  -11.8611  |  -3.93324     | X64    | 2021-07-08 00:00:00 |           839 |
| 32 |  -14.7177  |  -5.49304     | X64    | 2021-07-09 00:00:00 |           602 |
| 33 |  -14.3295  |  -3.38267     | X64    | 2021-07-10 00:00:00 |           440 |
| 34 |  -12.9083  |  -3.08062     | ARM    | 2021-07-11 00:00:00 |           715 |
| 35 |  -15.0703  |  -7.28629     | X64    | 2021-07-11 00:00:00 |           839 |
| 36 |  -16.4491  |  -8.55195     | X64    | 2021-07-12 00:00:00 |           796 |
| 37 |  -28.7721  |  18.1431      | ARM    | 2021-07-13 00:00:00 |            25 |

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in VegaLite https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5261